# How to grab this tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a real state web but I can't grab it.

This is what I want to grab:

[image: This is what I want to grab]

This is how my code looks:

```py
URL = requests.get('https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/venta/cali/?ad=30|1||||1|||||82|8200006||||||||||||||||1|||1||griddate%20desc||||||||',headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(URL,'lxml')
anuncios = soup.find_all('ul', attrs={'class':'advert  Product_Code_ AD_OV'})
print(anuncios)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "i can't grab it"?  Do you get an error?

Comment: 'web grabbing' is a synonym for 'web scraping'. But yes we need to know exactly why it fails, what error message or traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `URL.content` when you pass `URL` variable to `BeautifulSoup()`.

You can use this example how to get data from the page:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
}

url = requests.get(
    "https://www.fincaraiz.com.co/finca-raiz/venta/cali/?ad=30|1||||1|||||82|8200006||||||||||||||||1|||1||griddate%20desc||||||||",
    headers=headers,
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "lxml")
anuncios = soup.select("ul.advert.Product_Code_.AD_OV")

# print some data:
for a in anuncios:
    print(a.h2.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Apartamento en Cencar Yumbo
Apartamento en Zona Sur
Apartamento en Santa Teresita
Apartamento en Prados Del Norte
Apartamento en Bella Suiza
Apartamento en El Refugio
Apartamento en Pance
Casa en Las Delicias
Apartamento en Valle Del Lili
Apartamento en Santa Rita
Apartamento en Cristales
Apartamento en Pance
Apartaestudio en Pance
Apartamento en Las Vegas De Comfandi
Apartaestudio en Bella Suiza
Apartamento en Santa Monica
Apartamento en Valle Del Lili

...and so on.
```